# Javascript switch case - appropriate use for duplicate information?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

The use case:

```
switch(element.tagName){
    case 'STYLE':
        element.type = 'text/css';
    case 'LINK':
        element.rel = 'stylesheet';
        break;
}
```

In this case the `rel` needs to be applied to both. So the above doesn't have a `break;` after `case 'style:'` and the code works, and I understand it can do this - for `<style>` elements it added both `rel` and `type` and for `<link>` elements only have `rel` applied.

But is this an appropriate way to use it?

Comment: It's valid. I wouldn't say it's idiomatic though. Personally, I would just write `if (element.tagName === 'STYLE') { element.type = 'text/css'; } element.rel = 'stylesheet';`

Comment: Is this actually your use case? People don’t usually add `rel` to `<style>`. (Or `type` to either `<style>` or `<link rel="stylesheet">`, for that matter.) In fact, it’s invalid to put `rel="stylesheet"` on elements that aren’t `<link>`s, and `rel` in general on elements that aren’t links.

Comment: This is a use case I have, yes. I'm wondering more on flow-through and how it affects the outcome, if you will, rather than if the use case the most sense.

Comment: If you want to fall through, then fall through. Put in a comment saying you are falling through. You may need to add a lint directive to prevent it from complaining.

Comment: This is definitely valid, and flowing down a switch statement is half of why they exist, but for this case, I agree with @MikeC that an `if` would be much clearer.

Comment: @Linuxious this is only a small part of the use case. I'm using it to illustrate the fall through because it's only in this section of code.

Comment: There is a correct technical term for this, and it is neither "flow-through" or "flowing down". It is **fall-through**.